# Run a few additional commands after systemctl restart httpd on CentOS

Tags: command-line, centos, httpd.conf

I need to copy a bunch of files into some folder every time the httpd service restarts

e.g.:

> yes | cp ./dynamic/*.file /folder/inside/my/webapp

is there a way to run some additional commands when the httpd is restarted?

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

You can edit the httpd service file with:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full httpd.service
```

You should be able to add more directives to the service unit, such as running your additional commands.